# Socket accept gives error when I add socket_set_nonblock

Tags: php, sockets, websocket, php-socket

My code worked fine, but when I changed and added `socket_set_nonblock($socket)` socket_accept gave me error 11, here is my code

```
<?php
session_start();
require "checklogin.php";
error_reporting(0);
$user=$_SESSION["usr"];

set_time_limit(0);
ob_implicit_flush();
$host="127.0.0.1";
$port=11287;
$greeting="\nWelcome to my PHP server(listener)\nto quit type 'quit\nto shutdown the server type 'shutdown'.\n";

$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP) or die("Err: " . socket_last_error());
socket_bind($socket, $host, $port) or die("Err: " . socket_last_error());
if (!socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)) {}
$result = socket_listen($socket) or die("can't set up listener");
socket_set_nonblock($socket) or die("rip multiple: " . socket_last_error());
while (true) {
if ($spawn = socket_accept($socket) or die("err: can't accept - " . socket_last_error())) {
socket_write($spawn, $greeting, strlen($greeting));
}
do {

$input = socket_read($spawn, 1024, PHP_NORMAL_READ) or die("Could not read input\n");
socket_write($spawn, $user, strlen("needreload"));
echo $input . "<br>";



}
while (true);

socket_close($spawn);
}
socket_close($socket);
?>
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: don't `die` when socket_accept fails... if the return was `false`, just continue the loop (remember that you're in non-blocking mode now - there is no waiting for a connection anymore)

Comment: should I also remove die from socket_read?

Comment: `die` is always a bad choice in programming. But yes, you need to _handle_ it properly. Unfortunately in NB mode you cannot distinguish between "no data sent" and "client disconnected". Read the comments in docu of `socket_read`

Answer (score 1):

> ... but when I changed and added socket_set_nonblock($socket) socket_accept gave me error 11, ...

11 is EAGAIN / EWOULDBLOCK, meaning that the operation (`accept`) would block if the socket wasn't explicitly set to non-blocking. This is exactly the error which is expected when setting a socket to non-blocking and one has to deal with it by trying later again, ideally after checking with [select](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-select.php) that the file descriptor is ready for doing this operation. If you don't want this kind of error then don't set the socket to non-blocking.